# Expecting a Declaration C++

Tags: c++

This has been driving me nuts for the past couple of hours. I'm still quite new to C++ so the answer may be very simple.

This is for a header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class Band

{

public:

    int blk;
    int brn;
    int r;
    int o;
    int y;
    int gn;
    int blu;
    int p;
    int gy;
    int whi;

    Band();
    {
            blk = 0;
            brn = 1;
            r = 2;
            o = 3;
            y = 4;
            gn = 5;
            blu = 6;
            p = 7;
            gy = 8;
            whi = 9;
    }
};
```

The second { bracket right under Band(); is receiving an error saying "expected a declaration." The whole code is there so nothing should be missing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `Band();` get rid of semi-colon

Comment: `This has been driving me nuts for the past couple of hours.`Dont take me wrong but I think you need a break as you missed a small semicolon near Band() ;)

Comment: Your member names remind me of `std::basic_streambuf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon.

```
Band(); // this one
{
```

Comment: It really was that simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
Band();
   // ^
{
    // ...
```

The semicolon is superflous here!
Either you put a declaration for the constructor in your header file (with the semicolon) and leave out the body. Or you have the definition within your header file and leave out the semicolon.

Also consider to use a member initializer list to initialize your class member variables, instead of doing this in the constructor body. This might be more efficient, especially for non-primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the constructor to

```
Band()
{
        blk = 0;
        brn = 1;
        r = 2;
        o = 3;
        y = 4;
        gn = 5;
        blu = 6;
        p = 7;
        gy = 8;
        whi = 9;
};
```